# Haskell: inline auxiliary function into do block

Tags: haskell, input, output, monads

Working through *Programming in Haskell* (Second Edition) by Graham Hutton, I just managed to solve exercise 10.5 (page 138). The task is to write a function `adder :: IO ()` that reads `n` numbers (to be defined interactively), sums them up, and prints the result, like so:

```
> adder
How many numbers? 3
5
4
6
The total is 15
```

The functions `readInt` and `readLine` are already given as:

```hs
readInt :: IO Int
readInt = do
  line <- readLine
  return (read line :: Int)

readLine :: IO String
readLine = do
  c <- getChar
  case c of
    '\n' -> return []
    _ -> do
      cs <- readLine
      return (c:cs)
```

So I just had to write the `adder` function:

```hs
adder :: IO ()
adder = do
  putStr "How many numbers? "
  n <- readInt
  ns <- sequence [readInt | _ <- [1..n]]
  sum <- sumUp ns
  putStr $ "The total is " ++ (show sum) ++ "\n"

sumUp :: [Int] -> IO Int
sumUp xs = return $ foldl (+) 0 xs
```

I'm almost happy with my solution, but I'd just like to inline the `sumUp` function. However, I have no idea how to do it.

How can I inline a `[a] -> IO a` function into a `do` block?

Comment: You just use the equality you wrote. `sumUp ns = return $ foldl (+) 0 ns`, so the `sumUp ns` in `sum <- sumUp ns` can be replaced with the RHS of that equation: `sum <- return $ foldl (+) 0 ns`. (But this is not a real answer, because in this specific case there are better solutions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `return` here, we can use [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to sum up the numbers:

```
adder :: IO ()
adder = do
  putStr "How many numbers? "
  n <- readInt
  ns <- sequence [readInt | _ <- [1 .. n]]
  putStr $ "The total is " ++ (show (sum ns)) ++ "\n"
```

We can also repeat `readInt` through [**`replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM):

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

adder :: IO ()
adder = do
  putStr "How many numbers? "
  ns <- readInt >>= (`replicateM` readInt)
  putStrLn $ "The total is " ++ (show (sum ns))
```

as for `readInt`, this can be implemented as:

```
readInt :: IO Int
readInt = readLn
```